# How can I get emacs24 fonts to smooth like in the terminal?

Tags: emacs

I've seen the question asked many times, but I can't find an answer which works.  I've tried editing .Xresources.

But in the end, I cannot get emacs fonts to look as nice as they do in the terminal.

[image]

Has anyone worked this out?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I worked this out.  Maybe it will save someone else.

Full hinting is evil.  In other words, I needed:

```
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
```

Instead of

```
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
```

Along with

```
Xft.dpi:        96
Xft.antialias:  true
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
```

In `~/.Xdefaults`.  Then `xrdb -merge .Xdefaults` and finally emacs looks beautiful again.